# How get the next page after login with PhatomJs?

Tags: javascript, php, curl, web-scraping, phantomjs

I have found so many questions about this on here, but not sure why they are not answered.

I am trying to crawl a web page after logging in with this code : [source](http://code-epicenter.com/how-to-login-amazon-using-phantomjs-working-example/)

```
var steps=[];
var testindex = 0;
var loadInProgress = false;//This is set to true when a page is still loading

/*********SETTINGS*********************/
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36';
page.settings.javascriptEnabled = true;
page.settings.loadImages = false;//Script is much faster with this field set to false
phantom.cookiesEnabled = true;
phantom.javascriptEnabled = true;
/*********SETTINGS END*****************/

console.log('All settings loaded, start with execution');
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};
/**********DEFINE STEPS THAT FANTOM SHOULD DO***********************/
steps = [

    //Step 1 - Open Amazon home page
    function(){
        console.log('Step 1 - Abrindo página de login');
        page.open("http://parceriascury.housecrm.com.br", function(status){

        });
    },
    //Step 3 - Populate and submit the login form
    function(){
        console.log('Step 3 - Preenchendo o form');
        page.evaluate(function(){
            document.getElementById("login").value="xxxxx";
            document.getElementById("senha").value="xxxxx";
            document.getElementById("frmlandingpage").submit();
        });
    },
    //Step 4 - Wait Amazon to login user. After user is successfully logged in, user is redirected to home page. Content of the home page is saved to AmazonLoggedIn.html. You can find this file where phantomjs.exe file is. You can open this file using Chrome to ensure that you are logged in.
    function(){
        console.log("Step 4 - Wait Amazon to login user. After user is successfully logged in, user is redirected to home page. Content of the home page is saved to AmazonLoggedIn.html. You can find this file where phantomjs.exe file is. You can open this file using Chrome to ensure that you are logged in.");
         var fs = require('fs');
         var result = page.evaluate(function() {
            return document.documentElement.outerHTML;
        });
        fs.write('C:\\phantomjs\\logado_cury_10.html',result,'w');
    },
];
/**********END STEPS THAT FANTOM SHOULD DO***********************/

//Execute steps one by one
interval = setInterval(executeRequestsStepByStep,5000);

function executeRequestsStepByStep(){
    if (loadInProgress == false && typeof steps[testindex] == "function") {
        //console.log("step " + (testindex + 1));
        steps[testindex]();
        testindex++;
    }
    if (typeof steps[testindex] != "function") {
        console.log("test complete!");
        phantom.exit();
    }
}

/**
 * These listeners are very important in order to phantom work properly. Using these listeners, we control loadInProgress marker which controls, weather a page is fully loaded.
 * Without this, we will get content of the page, even a page is not fully loaded.
 */
page.onLoadStarted = function() {
    loadInProgress = true;
    console.log('Loading started');
};
page.onLoadFinished = function() {
    loadInProgress = false;
    console.log('Loading finished');
};
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};
```

But the response only this:

```
<html><head></head><body>ok</body></html>
```

I need to get the content of next page with URL:

```
http://parceriascury.housecrm.com.br/parceiro_busca
```

I can access this page directly, but not with all complements, because it needs to be logged in.

No errors and I don't know where I am making a mistake.

**Edit**
Other solutions are welcome, i think maybe `curl`...But after js loading...

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: looks like you're getting the post-authentication frame, an empty page that just says 'ok'. add a timer or a selectorchange to make sure you wait long enough for the redirect to happen

Comment: Yes, looks like this, but when i login with manual method, after login, redirect to this another page and i cant see `ok`: `http://parceriascury.housecrm.com.br/parceiro_busca`, you have a little tip for me to succeed ? Tks for atention...

Comment: You can add [phantom.onError](http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/handler/on-error.html) callback and [page.onError](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code could be better:

```
var loadInProgress = false;//This is set to true when a page is still loading

/*********SETTINGS*********************/
var page = require('webpage').create({viewportSize:{width: 1600,height: 900},
settings:{userAgent:'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36',
javascriptEnabled:'true',
loadImages:'false'
}});
var fs = require('fs');
/*********SETTINGS END*****************/
console.log('All settings loaded, start with execution');

/**
 * These listeners are very important in order to phantom work properly. Using these listeners, we control loadInProgress marker which controls, weather a page is fully loaded.
 * Without this, we will get content of the page, even a page is not fully loaded.
 */
page.onLoadStarted = function() {
    loadInProgress = true;
    console.log('Loading started');
};
page.onLoadFinished = function() {
    loadInProgress = false;
    console.log('Loading finished');
};
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};

//Log in to your account, then view the cookie you got, now you can use these cookies to login
   // the site will recognize you with your cookies.

//for freebitco.in auth
phantom.cookies = [{// an array of objects
  'name'     : 'btc_address',   
  'value'    : '1AuMxR6sPtB2Z6TkahSnpmm1H4KpYPBKqe',  
  'domain'   : 'freebitco.in',        
  'path'     : '/',
  'httponly' : false,
  'secure'   : true,
  'expires'  : (new Date()).getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 43800) //5 years 
},{ 'name'     : 'password',   
  'value'    : 'f574ca68a8650d1264d38da4b7687ca3bf631e6dfc59a98c89dd2564c7601f84', 
  'domain'   : 'freebitco.in',        
  'path'     : '/',
  'httponly' : false,
  'secure'   : true,
  'expires'  : (new Date()).getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 43800) }]

//Execute steps one by one
page.open("http://parceriascury.housecrm.com.br/parceiro_busca", function(status){
console.log('Step 1 has been completed - we are on the target page!');
setTimeout(step2,5000);// Maybe we don't need to wait here, we can execute step2 immediately.
function step2(){
console.log("Step 2 - Content of the home page is saved to AmazonLoggedIn.html. You can find this file where phantomjs.exe file is. You can open this file using Chrome to ensure that you are logged in.");
var result = page.evaluate(function(){ return document.documentElement.outerHTML; });
fs.write('C:\\phantomjs\\logado_cury_10.html',result,'w');
phantom.exit(); 
}
});
```

Comment: can you explain why the above code is better than what OP posted?

Comment: @MagicHat oh, sorry.
an error was here: `console.log('Step 1 has been completed - we're on the login page!');` -- there shouldn't be an apostrophe in the `we're`, or at least should be `we\'re`

Comment: @Sid basically, much clearer and shorter which is better.

Comment: and it seems, an address to open should be `http://parceriascury.housecrm.com.br/parceiro` not `http://parceriascury.housecrm.com.br`

Comment: @Igor Tks for help, but i change all things what u sad, and the code work like other... with response `<html><head></head><body>ok</body></html>`, i dont know more what do....

Comment: @MagicHat [Try to use SlimerJS and/or fake navigator object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40876840/how-to-avoid-google-captcha-with-phantomjs-working-private-proxies-catch-it#40877338)

Comment: Phantomjs is not to this objective ?

Comment: Phantomjs is worse, because have less of functions in the window object, on some pages SlimerJS is better

Comment: tks a lot man... this cokkies save my life,,,, cant +2 ...tks again

Comment: @MagicHat that could be done even shorter, cuz `phantom.cookies` is not [document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) - we don't need an intermediate page at all. And also, Instead of `window.location.href` can be used `location`.